# Can MS Access send emails through Gmail using single sign on in a Google Chrome browser?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I think the title says it all.  I can send emails using outlook but now we switched to Gmail and lost all of our notification functionality in our databases.

Comment: You can use outlook to open your mail from gmail...

Comment: That is what we have done as an interim step but I am concerned that eventually we will not have Outlook installed on our PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send mails from Access using gmail accounts. You need CDO library-reference. Search for it ("cdo"+"access"+"send" "mail")

Then, you send them with a function like this (comments in spanish):

```
Function Enviar_Mail_CDO(Para As String, _
                         De As String, _
                         Asunto As String, _
                         Mensaje As String, _
                         Usuario As String, _
                         Password As String, _
                         Optional Path_Adjunto As String) As Boolean



'Me.MousePointer = vbHourglass

' Variable de objeto Cdo.Message
Dim Obj_Email As CDO.Message


Dim SerVidor_SMTP As String
Dim Puerto As String
Dim Usar_Autentificacion As Boolean
Dim usar_ssl As Boolean

SerVidor_SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"
Puerto = "465"
Usar_Autentificacion = True
usar_ssl = True


' Crea un Nuevo objeto CDO.Message
Set Obj_Email = New CDO.Message

' Indica el servidor Smtp para poder enviar el Mail ( puede ser el nombre _
  del servidor o su dirección IP )
Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServer) = SerVidor_SMTP

Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod) = 2

' Puerto. Por defecto se usa el puerto 25, en el caso de Gmail se usan los puertos _
  465 o  el puerto 587 ( este último me dio error )

Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = CLng(Puerto)


' Indica el tipo de autentificación con el servidor de correo _
 El valor 0 no requiere autentificarse, el valor 1 es con autentificación
Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/" & _
            "configuration/smtpauthenticate") = Abs(Usar_Autentificacion)



    ' Tiempo máximo de espera en segundos para la conexión
Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30


' Configura las opciones para el login en el SMTP
If Usar_Autentificacion Then

' Id de usuario del servidor Smtp ( en el caso de gmail, debe ser la dirección de correro _
 mas el @gmail.com )
Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = Usuario

' Password de la cuenta
Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = Password

' Indica si se usa SSL para el envío. En el caso de Gmail requiere que esté en True
Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = usar_ssl

End If


' *********************************************************************************
' Estructura del mail
'**********************************************************************************

' Dirección del Destinatario
Obj_Email.To = Para

' Dirección del remitente
Obj_Email.From = De

' Asunto del mensaje
Obj_Email.Subject = Asunto

' Cuerpo del mensaje
Obj_Email.TextBody = Mensaje

'Ruta del archivo adjunto

If Path_Adjunto <> vbNullString Then
    Obj_Email.AddAttachment (Path_Adjunto)
End If

' Actualiza los datos antes de enviar
Obj_Email.Configuration.Fields.Update

On Error Resume Next
' Envía el email
Obj_Email.Send


If Err.Number = 0 Then
   Enviar_Mail_CDO = True
Else
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, " Error al enviar el amil "
End If

' Descarga la referencia
If Not Obj_Email Is Nothing Then
    Set Obj_Email = Nothing
End If

On Error GoTo 0
'Me.MousePointer = vbNormal
```

End Function

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!  How secure are the users passwords when they are being send from and Access macro?  I am concerned with users putting their account passwords into Access for this function.  We use single sign on so when Chrome is opened our email page comes up automatically (seems trivial but I'm new to this).  Can Chrome be controlled by Access using HTML or something similar to generate these emails so the SMPT isn't used?

Comment: I am not very sure I understand your last point. FOLLOWS... What I dit is to use several generic accounts (sendmail1@domain.com,sendmail2@domain.com,...) to send the mails through Access. You don't need to open Chrome to send them. Several accounts, because of the dayly message limit. Other way would be get username from the Access form, and ask for the password through an inbox.

Comment: I would like to make this as seamless and user friendly as possible.  With Outlook and Access the email just sent but now each time your saying that the username and password would need to be either stored in the database or input by the user every time.

Comment: Quite difficult to send the mail without neither store the password nor getit at the moment. As I told you, I used an on purpose account (sendmail@domain.com); this way, users just had to press a button on a Access form.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Can you confirm if the CDO SendPassword is secure?